# Blob upload to Azure

Tags: android, azure, upload, storage, blob

I am playing with the Sample Storage app for android on Azure mobile back end. I am having a hard time getting it to work. My emulator does not work with mobile service at all so I don't have a log etc. to help. There are no build errors and the app runs fine - just doesn't upload the blob. I am pretty sure I know exactly where it stops functioning. It works fine through selecting the image and creating the sas url but then it doesn't actually upload. The container was set up earlier...

Here is the code where it seems to be bombing out and the insert server script below that.

Any help hugely appreciated....

Relevant client code:

```
 class ImageUploaderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {


    private String mUrl;
    public ImageUploaderTask(String url) {
        mUrl = url;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in imageuploader",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), url,
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // both these toasts showing up and there is proper looking url so seem fine up to 
            //   here - to get here have to get the sas url, access container, etc. 

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {  



        try {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in the TRY ",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // This toast not showing up so it seems like not even in this loop...why???



            //Get the image data
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mImageUri, null,null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex`enter code here  `enter code here`
                            (MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            String absoluteFilePath = cursor.getString(index);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(absoluteFilePath);
            int bytesRead = 0;
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            while ((bytesRead = fis.read(b)) != -1) {
                bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
            // Post our image data (byte array) to the server
            URL url = new URL(mUrl.replace("\"", ""));
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) 
                            url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""+ bytes.length);
            // Write image data to server



            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream

                            (urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(bytes);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            int response = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            //If we successfully uploaded, return true
            if (response == 201
                    && urlConnection.getResponseMessage().equals 
                           ("Created")) 
                            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "output successful",
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
        }
        return false;           
    }




Server Insert Script


var azure = require('azure');
var qs = require('querystring');

function insert(item, user, request) {

var accountName = 'private';
var accountKey = '+private';
var host = accountName + '.blob.core.windows.net';
var blobService = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accountKey, host);

var sharedAccessPolicy = { 
    AccessPolicy: {
        Permissions: 'rw', //Read and Write permissions
        Expiry: minutesFromNow(5) 
    }
};

var sasUrl = blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(request.parameters.containerName,
                request.parameters.blobName, sharedAccessPolicy);

var sasQueryString = { 'sasUrl' : sasUrl.baseUrl + sasUrl.path + '?' + qs.stringify 
(sasUrl.queryString) };                    
          request.respond(200, sasQueryString);

}

function minutesFromNow(minutes) {
var date = new Date()
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + minutes);  
return date;
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the blob type request header (`x-ms-blob-type`)? Try by adding the following line of code: `urlConnection.addRequestProperty("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");` after this line: `urlConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");`. See this link for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179451.aspx. Also, please tell us what's the error message you're getting?

Comment: Thanks! No error messages - my emulator doesn't connect to azure for some reason and when I run the app on my phone and try to create the blob nothing happens. The app doesn't crash or get stuck. Just doesn't do anything after the create button is pressed. The button works. I can tell through the toasts I set up that it goes through a lot of the process but doesn't get through the uploader as per my note above. Where should I place the code? The problem I have is the lack a beginning to end tutorial on blob storage. Hard for a beginner to figure it out from disjointed samples and docs.

Comment: I see you’re constructing http requests manually. I’m not sure why the code you posted is failing, but if you’re trying to use Azure storage you can simplify it significantly by using the storage client library for Android [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android). The Azure blob storage doc [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage/) should help you get started using that library.